# Why my virtual assignment operator not doing as intended?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, assignment-operator

```
    class Base{
       public:
       virtual Base& operator=( const Base& ) {
          std::cout << "Base::operator=( const Base& )" << std::endl;
          return *this;
       }
    };

    class Derived: public Base{
       public:
       virtual Derived& operator=( const Base& ) {
          std::cout << "Derived::operator=( const Base& )" << std::endl;
          return *this;
       }
       virtual Derived& operator=( const Derived& ) {
          std::cout << "Derived::operator=( const Derived& )" << std::endl;
          return *this;
       }
    };

    int main(){
        Derived obj1, obj2;
        Base& ba=obj2;
        obj1=ba;//outputs[1]: Derived::operator=( const Base&)

        Derived& de=obj2;
        obj1=de;//outputs[2]: Derived::operator=( const Derived& )

        Base& bb=obj2;
        bb=obj1; //outputs[3]: Derived::operator=( const Base&)
     }
```

I am confused on the case 3 output, shouldn't assignment operator take the right operand as the function argument, so that **obj1** is taken as the argument and since **obj1** is class type of Derived, so it will call **Derived::operator=( const Derived& )**?

For the output[3], why the output is **Derived::operator=( const Base& )**, not **Derived::operator=( const Derived& )**?

Comment: Signatures don't match.

Comment: You are calling `bb.operator=(obj1);` At compile time, name lookup and overload resolution are performed to find a suitable overload; the only candidate is `Base::operator=(const Base&)`. At run-time, the override of that method in the most-derived class is called - that would be `Derived::operator=(const Base&)`. You are looking for double dispatch; C++ doesn't support it directly.

Comment: @Igor Maybe worth a formal answer? This is actually a very interesting scenario.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969232/why-does-virtual-assignment-behave-differently-than-other-virtual-functions-of-t).

Answer (score 2):

The `Derived::operator=( const Derived& )` has no override candidate in the Base class. I suggest adding `override` keyword after each method which is intended to override base class behavior. It costs nothing and can make your code much safer.

If you want to the `Derived::operator=( const Derived& )` to be called, you need to provide a correct method signature in the base class:

```
class Derived; // forward declaration

class Base{
       public:
       virtual Base& operator=( const Base& ) {
          std::cout << "Base::operator=( const Base& )" << std::endl;
          return *this;
       }

       virtual Base& operator=( const Derived& ) {
          std::cout << "Base::operator=( const Derived& )" << std::endl;
          return *this;
       }
    };

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    virtual Derived& operator=( const Base& ) override {
      std::cout << "Derived::operator=( const Base& )" << std::endl;
      return *this;
    }
    virtual Derived& operator=( const Derived& ) override {
      std::cout << "Derived::operator=( const Derived& )" << std::endl;
      return *this;
    }
};
```