# Why can't a Visual C++ interface contain operators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, interface, operator-overloading

As per the [MSDN doc on __interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50h7kwtb.aspx), a Visual C++ interface "Cannot contain constructors, destructors, or operators."

Why can't an interface contain an operator? Is there that much of a difference between a get method that returns a reference:

```
SomeType& Get(WORD wIndex);
```

and the overloaded indexer operator?

```
SomeType& operator[](WORD wIndex);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__interface` modifier is a Visual C++ extension to help implementing COM interfaces. This allows you to specify a COM 'interface' and enforces the COM interface rules.

And because COM is a C compatible definition, you cannot have operators, Ctor or Dtors.

Comment: So, if I want to have an "interface" with operators, is my only choice a pure virtual class?

Comment: Your "only choice" is to write a standard C++ class, yes. There are plenty of approaches depending on what you need. A pure abstract class is the closest you're going to get to Java/C# type interfaces, but in many cases, a better solution in C++ is to not define an interface. Use the duck-typing provided by templates, and simply define the concepts a class must support, and don't bother requiring it to derive anything. Or use the CRTP idiom to provide an interface for static polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a .dll thing.  You need a method name so you can use it other languages that don't support operator overloading, eg `C`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Interfaces cannot contain operators because operators cannot be virtual functions. Essentially interfaces are base classes that other classes derive from.</strike>

**Edit:** After reading the comments and thinking about this more I realized how stupid this was. Please forgive my eager fingers. Operators are no different than any other function. A more likely reason has to do with __interface generating classes which derive from a common base class, and the necessity for dlls to have all constructors, destructors, and assignment operators that they use locally.

Comment: Operators **can** be virtual, related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c

Comment: Operators can be virtual in standard C++. A lot of them shouldn't be, because for instance `operator=` should take a reference of the same type as parameter, and you can get into all sorts of trouble trying to do polymorphic assignment. But `operator[]` is a reasonable candidate for polymorphism. Admittedly the non-virtual interface idiom is often preferable in pure C++, but that's true of non-operator functions too.