# Tricky inheritance of operator= in abstract class hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, operator-overloading, abstract

I have this class hierarchy where I'm trying to add operator= :

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
    virtual A& operator=(const A&) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void someFunction() {
        //implementation
    }
    A& operator=(const A& o)
    {
        *ptr = *o.ptr;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    A* ptr;
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    void someFunction() {
        //implementation
    }
    A& operator=(const A& o)
    {
        data = o.data;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int data;  //NOTE: different members that needs to be copied in the operator
};
```

I understand why this doesn't work. I have a private member in B (that needs to be there) and a function `A&operator=(const A&)` that needs to be overwritten. Problem is that `o` is of type A and doesn't have the pointer `ptr`.

I've tried to dynamic_cast o to type B, but

1. that wont work since it's constant,
2. It seems unsafe (if rhs is of type C)

Same issue for class C.
Is there some cleaver work-around?

Clarification of why I need it this way:

```
class superClass
{
public:
  superClass& operator=(const superClass& o)
  {
    *some_A_type = *o.some_A_type;
  }
private:
  A* some_A_type;
};
```

essentially, what I want is an operator= for superClass. I'm not sure where or how to fix it.

Comment: Why is the assignment operator in `A` in the first place? I'd start with defending *that* decision first.

Comment: Because of how it's later used. I have a class X that must be able to store any type of A-child and perform operations on them.

Comment: Assuming for a moment that made sense, what do you *expect* to happen when you `B b; C c; b = c;` ? Storing a reference to an `A` derivation needs no assignment operator. It needs references and/or pointers to the real object, otherwise you're eventually staring down the throat of [a slicing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: That's why I said that dynamic_cast seems like a bad option. I want to be able to do `B b1, b2; C c1, c2; b1 = b2; c1 = c2;` but not `b1 = c1;`

Comment: Then you implement proper assignment for each class, leave it out of A, and use pointers (ideally smart ones) or references for your polymorphism.

Comment: Maybe you find an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c/669894#669894). Especially Brian R. Bondy's answer looks quite promising.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated the question to include my other class. Could you please explain where/how I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-consider your initial design of classes.

Also you should understand:

- operator polymorphism (`a + b` works for both `std::string` and `int`)
- data type cannot be polymorph by itself because memory layout should be defined
- what is abstract class and/or interface
- maybe static polymorphism would be useful too

First try to imagine what implication of having assignment between any object of any class within class `A`. I.e. to store object of `B` in object of `C` we should change state of object from `C` in that way that its characteristics will be equivalent object to original object from `B`. This can be achieved either by having common memory layout (i.e. all descendants store same data) between all descendants of `A` or by exposing same behavior in some other way like referencing to original object.

Note that behavior of `virtual void someFunction()` should also be copied.

Let's try to pull out maximum out of your sample:

```
// our interface
struct A {
    virtual void someFunction() = 0;
    // no polymorphic assignment
};  

struct B : A {
    void someFunction();
    B &operator=(const A &o)
    { ptr = &o; return *this; }
private:
    A *ptr;
}   

struct C : A {
    void someFunction();
    A &operator=(const C &o)
    { data = o.data; return *this; }
private:
    int data;
};

C c, c2;
B b;
A &a = c;
b = c; // ok
b = a; // ok
c = c2; // ok
c = b; // wrong
```

Or if you still want polymorphic assignment:

```
// interface. descendants are responsible for maintaining LSP
struct A {
    void someFunction()
    { cout << data(); }
    virtual int getData() const = 0;
    // assignment should result in copying chars and making getData() to behave like in original object
    virtual A &operator=(const A &o) = 0; 
};  

struct B : A {
    int getData() const { return ptr->getData(); }
    A &operator=(const A &o)
    { ptr = &o; return *this; }
private:
    const A *ptr;
};

struct C : A {
    int getData() const { return data; }
    A &operator=(const A &o)
    { data = o.getData(); return *this; }
private:
    int data;
};
```

P.S. Last variant probably unwanted in real world.

Answer (score 0):

Found in [similiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c/669894#669894) question sugested by TobiMcNamobi:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
  virtual A& operator=(const A& p)
  {
    *ptr = *o.ptr;
    return *this;
  }


  virtual B& operator=(const B& p)
  {
    //throw exception
  }

};
```

Comment: But you'll have to add methods for each descendant of A and in each descendant you'll have only one variant that doesn't throw exception. And finally everything (which method to call) will be decided in compile-time anyway. I.e. if you work in terms of `A` everywhere only `operator=(const A&)` will be called.