# c++ operator= weird behviour

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Help? I really have no idea what's happening here?
Why in line 3 of assignments it calls operator= of A, when its an assignment of B to B?

```
class A{
public: 
    A& operator=(const A&){cout << "A assignment" << endl;return *this;}
};

class B:public A{
public: 
    A& operator=(const A&){cout << "B assignment" << endl;return *this;}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    B b2;       
    a=b; //  output: A assignment
    b=a; //  output: B assignment
    b=b2; //  output: A assignment WHY??
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Doesn't compile](http://ideone.com/TWtPTP)

Comment: @jafar See my previous comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [virtual assignment operator C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I was trying to figure it our and changed it. It does compile now.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to understand why in b=b2 it goes to assignment operator of A, and not B, since I'm assigning to B right?

Comment: you cant assign `a` to `b`. Error: `binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'A' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined an assignment operator in `B`, but there's also another implicit copy-assignment operator generated by the compiler:

```
B& B::operator=(B const&);
```

This is a better match than the one that takes `A const&` so it is chosen in the assignment `b = b2` (since `b2` is a `B` it doesn't require a derived-to-base conversion for the one that takes an `A`). The implicit copy-assignment operator calls the copy-assignment operator of the base class which you wrote:

```
B& B::operator=(B const& b) {
    A::operator=(b);
    return *this;
}
```

This is why it looks like `A::operator=(A const&)` is being chosen by the assignment.

Comment: It seems like you're right, unless I explicitly overload B& B::operator=(B const& b) my self, It does what you say it does.

Answer (score 2):

There's still a compiler-generated assignment operator in class `B` (it's overloaded); unlike how this works with constructors, defining one or more assignment operator overloads does not prevent the compiler from generating a copy assignment operator when one is lacking. The compiler generated one calls `A::operator=`. And it's the better match for an argument of type `B`.

Comment: How is it a better match tho? They are exactly the same, are they not?

Comment: @MichaelPapkov: one overload (user-defined) takes an `A const&`, the other (compiler-generated) takes a `B const&`.