# Implementing virtual functions in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-keyword

I have an exercise dealing with classes in c++, in which I create a file system like so (`File.h`)

```
class File {
   public:
   virtual string getName();
   virtual void print() const=0;
   virtual bool operator==(const File& file) const=0;
}
```

Then, I implement `getName` in `File.cpp` and create `TextFile.h`

```
class TextFile : public File {
   public:
   void print() const;
   void operator==(const TextFile& textFile) const;

   private:
   string text_;
```

Implement in `TextFile.cpp`

```
void TextFile :: print() const {
   cout << text_ << endl;
}

bool TextFile :: operator==(const TextFile& textFile) const {
   return true; //just for compiling
}
```

when compiling we get:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g File.cpp TextFile.cpp -o  RunMe
TextFile.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
TextFile.cpp:8:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘Ilan’ to be of abstract type ‘TextFile’
  TextFile Ilan("Ilan", NULL, "Blah \n NewLine");
           ^
In file included from TextFile.cpp:1:0:
TextFile.h:8:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘TextFile’:
 class TextFile: public File
       ^
In file included from TextFile.h:4:0,
                 from TextFile.cpp:1:
File.h:57:18: note:     virtual bool File::operator==(const File&) const
     virtual bool operator==(const File& file) const = 0;
```

I probably don't know how to work well with inheritance and operator functions (seeing the `print` function works well), but I can't find the problem when looking through my course material.

Comment: Isn't the error message clear enough? You have to implement `operator==(const File& file) const`, not `operator==(const TextFile& file) const`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [virtual assignment operator C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c)

Comment: I looked at that question. Couldn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVERLOAD vs. OVERRIDE...

In `File` you declare the virtual function

```
bool operator==(const File & file) const
```

as pure. (`= 0`). So `File` is an abstract class, and so are its subclasses where it is not overridden.

In `TextFile`, you *overload* it with a function with the same name (`operator==`)

```
bool operator==(const TextFile & textFile) const
```

but you don't *override* it, because the parameters are not the same type. Consequently `TextFile` is an abstract class because

```
bool TextFile::operator==(const File & file) const
```

is still not defined.

EDIT: the compiler can detect such problems if you use the C++11 keyword "override". In `TextFile.h` :

```
class TextFile :  public File 
{
   ...
   void print()            const override;
   bool operator== (.....) const override; 
   ...
 }
```

a message will tell if the functions actually don't override when they are supposed to do.

Comment: So how do I make it compile? I want the function to work only for `TextFile` class. Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more specific ?  What do you mean by "work only for TextFile" ? If so, why declare it in File as a virtual function ?

Comment: Frankly It's declared there bc it's how I got `File.h` and I was asked not to change it. I can Implement it on 'File.cpp', but it would be pointless for it should compare the `string text_` field, which is only in `TextFile`

Comment: In this case, change the parameter type in TextFile::operator== to const File &. And use the C++11 keyword "override", so the compiler will check for you.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Won't it cause problem in the future (for calling a parent class from within the inheriting one, or something like that)?

Comment: Life is an endless cause of problems. Especially life with the C++ language.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that it can't declare Ilan to be of type "Textfile", because a "virtual function is pure", and then gives you the name of the pure virtual function.

In C++ a pure virtual function is one which has been declared virtual, and for which no implementation is defined.   If a class has *any pure virtual* functions, it is a virtual class, and you cannot create an instance of that class.   This is useful for creating abstract interfaces, which is what you have done with your parent class.

In your case, you have specified that the == operator is a class operator in the TextFile declaration, but you have defined the == operator in the global namespace.  To correct this, you can either *declare* the == operator in the global namespace, or define it as part of TextFile (as Ed Heal suggested), but you should prefer the former for the reasons discussed here: [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I used Michael Billaud's answer for now and it works great, but I will read your link later on, it looks good for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
bool operator==(const &TextFile textFile) const {
```

is incorrect - should be

```
  bool TextFile::operator==(const TextFile& textFile) const {
```

As it needs to be defined.

Comment: The whole code consists of typos, don't you see `const &TextFile`? It's obviously not a real code.

Comment: yes, that was a copying mistake, it has `TextFile ::` in my .cpp

Comment: @AntonSavin- Correct - I was in the process of editing it

Comment: @EdHeal anyway, with a TextFile parameter, it wont override File::operator==().

Answer (score 0):

File.h

```
class File {
   public:
   virtual string getName() const=0;
   virtual void print() const=0;
}；
```

---

TextFile.h

```
class TextFile : public File {
   public:
   string getName() const;
   void print() const;
   bool operator==(const TextFile& textFile) const;

   private:
   string text_;
};
```

---

TextFile.cpp

```
string TextFile ::getName() const{
   return text_;
}
void TextFile :: print() const {
   cout << text_ << endl;
}

bool TextFile :: operator==(const TextFile& textFile) const {
   return text_==textFile.text_; 
}
```