# Virtual surdefinition of operator =

Tags: c++

I have two classes, and I want to surdefine the operator = .

```
class Composant {

string description;

...

virtual const Composant& operator=(const Composant &c)
{
    description = c.description;
    return *this;
}

}
```

And the other one inherited :

```
class Ecran : Composant {

int format, pitch;
double taille;

...

const Ecran& operator=(const Ecran &e)
{
    format = e.format;
    taille = e.taille;
    pitch = e.pitch;

    //traiter composant
    Composant::operator=(e);
}
```

Example of the code in the main :

```
Composant *p=new Ecran(.....);
Composant *t=new Ecran(.....);
(*p)=*t;
```

Is this the correct way to do it ?

I assume that we **MUST** put the surdefinition of the operator = in virtual, everytime we have this type of inheritance then ? same for the operator == and so on ...

Comment: `operator=(const Composant &c)` and `operator=(const Ecran &e)` are completely different methods. Note that you are changing the parameter type, creating an overloaded operator. The latter is not overriding the former.

Comment: @dhke Member functions in different classes don't overload.

Comment: `Composant *p=new Ecran` will not compile. Try it!

Comment: @curiousguy What makes you think I cannot add another method with the same name as a method in the derived class that only differs in the parameters (which my nomenclature still calls *overloading* because I'm re-using the name)? But nitpicking aside, the thing is `Ecran` has two different `operator=()`, not a single virtual one.

Comment: @curiousguy That's because there's no `:public Composant` in the inheritance list. But I think it's more or less clear from the question that this is a mistake.

Comment: @curiousguy Since when do data members have parameters? *Function* overloading specifically refers to the technique of re-using a function name so that different versions are used in different contexts. In this case, we have function overloading based on parameter type. If `Base` has `doit(int)` and `Derived` has `doit(long)` the parameter type decides which one get's called. Hence `doit()` is overloaded for all instances of `Derived`. What else do you call that, because it's clearly not polymorphism?

Comment: @dhke "_Function overloading specifically refers to the technique_" no, overloading means that more than one function of a given name can be declared in one scope "_If Base has doit(int) and Derived has doit(long) the parameter type decides which one get's called_" no, the type of the object does

Comment: @curiousguy Nah, crap, I forgot it's C++ *sigh* You need a `using Base::doit` to get the behaviour I would expected (and think sane). Sorry for the noise. It's still overloading, mind you ;-)

Comment: @dhke "_It's still overloading,_" not according to the standard

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to do it?

No virtual dispatch is going in:

```
(*p)=*t;
```

You are just calling `Composant::operator=`. Whether this is the correct way to do it or not depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Defining a virtual `operator=` is possible [but not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669894/493122).

Comment: How does Composant know how to use the operator = of Ecran if we put nothing in virtual ? See,  i used pointers of Composant ...

Answer (score 1):

```
const Ecran& operator=(const Ecran &e)
{
    format = e.format;
    taille = e.taille;
    pitch = e.pitch;

    //traiter composant
    Composant::operator=(e);
}
```

must return a value

```
return *this;
```

`(*p)=*t;` calls `operator=` of `Composant` class not `Ecran` class since this operates on `Composant`.
You can define

```
virtual const Composant& operator=(const Composant &c);
```

in `Ecran` class and this would be called, however it will not have access to the member of `Ecran` in the right hand of the operator.