# Assignment operator and class inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, operator-overloading

Suppose the following case (Dreaded Diamond):

### EXAMPLE

```
   class Base //It's the Base class
{
    //...
    Base& operator=(const Base&); //Copy construct
    //...
};

class Derived1:virtual public Base
{
    //...
    Derived1& operator=(const Derived1&);
    //...
}

class Derived2:virtual public Base
{
    //...
    Derived2& operator=(const Derived2&);
    //...
}

class Derived12:public Derived1, public Derived2
{
    //...
    Derived12& operator=(const Derived12&);
    //...
}
```

Example:

```
//...
Base* object1 = new Derived12; 
Base* object2 = new Derived12;

*object1 = *object2;  //this line
//...
```

---

### PROBLEM

When ***"this line"*** is performed, the ***"operator="*** function, from ***Base***, is called.

Yet *the result I seek is not this*. I would like the assignment operator applied to be the one specified in ***Derived12*** class.
I understand that [overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) **"operator="** function is impossible, because the signature of each function would differ from class to class.

---

### QUESTION

1. Is there any way to make the compiler understand what is the assignment function I want to be applied ?
2. If it's not possible with operator overloading, *can you suggest some other way*?

---

Thank you, in advance, for any suggestion.

---

**UPDATE:**

First, **about** the ***Suggested Question Similar To Mine***. *It does not answer my question*. There I understood that in case I have an assignment of derived class object to base class object, the *operator=* in base class may just fill it's "untouched", during assignment, members with some default values.

Here I asked whether it's possible to make the compiler see -- that's the derived class I'm referring to and not the base. I would like to, somehow, make the assignment work with derived class members and not with the base ones.

I think I should explain the purpose of my question.

I have a similar problem I want to solve. Speaking in terms of the example above: I want to create an array of pointers to objects of mixed types: Derived, Derived1, Derived12 (each time a new object is created, the program checks if it's already present in array: if yes - new object isn't added, if no - the new object is assigned to the next uninitialized object in array.) I thought that using an array of pointers to base class would be the solution, but then encountered this problem. May be it's not the best method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtual assignment operator C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96527/discussion-on-question-by-john-g-assignment-operator-and-class-inheritance).