# operator overloading to another class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How override operator+ in first class to second class. I found more information about this but it does not work. Please help me

```
virtual Array& operator+(const double b) {
        cout << "Добавление числа 10: ";
        Array& x(*this);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        }
        cout << x << endl;
        return x;
    }

virtual ArrayComplex& operator+(const double b) {
        cout << "Добавление числа 1011111111111: ";
        ArrayComplex& x(*this);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            x[i] += 10;
        }
        cout << x << endl;
        return *this;
    }
```

Comment: What behavior did you notice that makes you think that the function does not work?

Comment: Do not override

Comment: Works for me. https://ideone.com/Lz9baw.

Comment: It is interesting but i use RTTI. Is it can influence for that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem you are running into. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Normally the workings of an expression `some_array+b` would actually use the value of `b` somewhere in the `operator+()`.   Neither of your definitions use the argument `b`.    It is probably better not to have them as virtual functions - the effects may not be what you intend.

Comment: https://ideone.com/6kQ1HG

Comment: This function do not override

Comment: From your ideone code: `prog.cpp:39:2: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 };` Add the close bracket for first class.

Comment: I only show how i white my class

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your base class `Array& operator+(const double b)` does not match the derived `ArrayComplex& operator+(const double b)` that's why it does not work. Make sure the return types are the same.

Comment: Down voted because it's a low quality explaination. What was missing in the users code? What about some general information about the mechasim which You understand, but is incorrectly implemented in the question?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, thank you for the explanation, will remember next time :)

Comment: Fix Your answer, and the downvote will be changed to an upvote or none. A downvote costs the giver -1 point. It's there to tell You to fix something.

Comment: But i saw this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c