# Pure virtual assignment operator in c++

Tags: c++

I have a base class

```
class Base{
public:
virtual ~Base();

};
```

I derive two classes from Base:

```
class D1:public Base{
//...some fields
//assignment operator, it does the deep copy of the members
D1& operator=(const D1&);
};

class D2:public Base{
//...some fields
//assignment operator, it does the deep copy of the members
D2& operator=(const D2&);
};
```

Next, in main I have two objects of let's say `D1`. The problem is that the overriden assignment operator is never called, however default one for base is called. I tried to make assignment operator virtual in `Base`, but it didn't help.

```
D1 *d1 = new D1();
D1 *d1_another = new D1();
//this doesn't work:
d1 = d1_another

D2 *d2 = new D2();
D2 *d2_another = new D2();
//this doesn't work:
d2 = d2_another
```

**UPD** 
Also I would like to know how to deal with

```
Base *d1 = new D1();
Base *d1_another = new D1();
//?
d1 = d1_another
```

Comment: you assign the pointers... [this way](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/728183b3c839551e)

Comment: @user1810087 `*d1 = *d1_another`?

Comment: @PavloKovalov: Try it and see.

Comment: exactly, see link :)

Comment: @user1810087 tnank you!

Comment: @user1810087, but what to do if I need to assign `Base* d1 = new D1()` to `Base* d1_another = new D1()`? if I write `*d1 = *d1_another` assignment operator prints nothing

Comment: Base and D1 are distict types in this case and the compiler does not know how to assign them, since D1 can have additional "fields". You need to define your own assginments for **all** types you want to cover. [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9946c26f371f6fc5). see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669894/1810087) a good discussion.

Comment: Assignment and derived classes don't play well togetger. Combining them is a design error more often than not. You hovever are never assugning any base or derived objects. You are only assigning pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try it like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

};


class D1 : public Base {
public:
    virtual ~D1() {}
    //...some fields
    //assignment operator, it does the deep copy of the members
    D1& operator=(const D1&) {
        cout << "D1:operator=(const D1&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

class D2 : public Base {
public:
    virtual ~D2() {}
    //...some fields
    //assignment operator, it does the deep copy of the members
    D2& operator=(const D2&) {
        cout << "D2:operator=(const D2&)\n";
        return *this;
    }
};
```

### main

```
    D1 *d1 = new D1();
    D1 *d1_another = new D1();
    //this doesn't work:
    *d1 = *d1_another;

    D2 *d2 = new D2();
    D2 *d2_another = new D2();
    //this doesn't work:
    *d2 = *d2_another;
```

Comment: Why did you add virtual destructors to `D1` and `D2`? Not virtual won't work?

Comment: @PavloKovalov because if you want to work with some raw pointers , then it is necessary

Comment: if the base class destructor is virtual then the derived class destructor is also virtual you don't need to specify  it virtual explicitly

Comment: so in derived class `~destructor()` is the same as `virtual ~destructor()`, in case when base has virtual destructor?

Comment: @PavloKovalov yes exactly

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you please suggest smth regarding upd? I've updated the question. I suppose I have to do some casting, but not sure how to do that

Comment: Okay, but I don’t have enough reputation(

Comment: try it the same way . `*d1 = *d1_another;`

Comment: Ok, just a minute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479931/use-of-assignment-operator-of-derived-class-in-base here it is

Comment: @PavloKovalov you probably should **not** ask a new question. there are already a lot of them if you search for inheritance, assignment... well to late...