# Use of assignment operator of derived class in base

Tags: c++

I have a class `Base`

```
class Base{
    public:
    virtual ~Base();
    //I'm not sure about this, should it be virtual, or should it be "pure" virtual?
    virtual Base& operator=(const Base&);
}
```

If `Base` class is derived by several classes like

```
class Derived1: public Base{
    //...data 
    //standard assignment operator, it works for objects of class Derived1
    Derived1& operator=(const Derived&){
    //perform deep copy here
        std::cout<<"Derived1 assignment operator"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Each of these classes must have assignment operator, because some data members of the classes are pointers, and I have to deep copy them. Then the following code doesn't work:

```
Base *d1 = new Derived1();
Base *d1_another = new Derived1();
//assignment operator is not called.
*d1 = *d1_another
```

If I make the base's assignment operator to be pure virtual, `virtual Base& operator=(const Base&) = 0`, then it have to be implemented in each subclass.

```
class Derived1: public Base{
    //...data 
    //implementation of the base's assignment operator
    Base& operator=(const Base&){
    //how to access Derived1 fields? Casting?
    }
}
```

But how do I copy the members of subclasses, If the object passed to assignment operator is `Base`?

P.S I know that this is not a very good design, but how should I do it, if, suppose, I have a vector of pointers to objects of Base `std::vector<Base*> v` and it is filled with objects of derived classes (`Derived1`, `Derived2`,some other classes) and sometimes I have to copy one object into another. I can't understand what is another solution to do this.

Comment: You will have to do something else, this is not going to be extensible and work in the long term. That's why you have pointers and that's why you use pointers to these objects to move them around. What happens if you have a `Derived1` and assign it to a `Derived2`?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, that's not gonna happen. Suppose that I have an integer variable called `type` in each class ( and in the base class as well), and it's equal to 1 if class is Derived1, 2 if Derived2, simply check before assigning objects

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher maybe this solution is stupid, but I only consider if objects of the same classes are assigned

Comment: Really, go back to the board and start from scratch, this is a very bad design.

Comment: If you need to assign objects one to another, might be more appropriate to have different vectors for each type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the argument to the assignment operator is not an *object* of `Base`, but a *reference* to `Base`. That means you can use e.g. [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to down-cast it to a reference to a `Derived1` object.

You could possibly also use [the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (or CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to declare the assignment operator in the `Base` class using the proper type for the argument and return.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `operator=` for this sort of thing. How do you deal with assigning a `Derived2` to a `Derived1`?

Instead, I would have an `assign` that had indicated success or failure, e.g.

```
class Base{
    protected:
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;
    public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual bool assign(const Base&) = 0;
    /* maybe ? virtual bool assign(Base&&) = 0; */
}

class Derived1: public Base{
    //...data 
    protected:
    Derived1& operator=(const Derived1 &) = default;
    public:
    bool assign(const Base & base){
        if (const Derived1 * derived = dynamic_cast<const Derived1 *>(&base))
        {
            *this = *derived;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    Base *d1 = new Derived1();
    Base *d1_another = new Derived1();
    Base *d2 = new Derived2();

    //assignment operator is not called.
    assert(d1->assign(*d1_another)); // expect true, d1 is changed
    assert(!d2->assign(*d1_another)); // expect false, d2 is unchanged
}
```

Comment: I don’t assign `Derived1` to `Derived2`. You can assume that I always assign objects of the same class. `Derived1` to `Derived1`, `Derived2` to `Derived2`

Comment: As far as I understand, dynamic casting will be susuccessful only if &base is a reference to object of derived1 class?

Comment: @PavloKovalov a pointer cast always results in a value, whereas a reference cast throws if the types don't match. I'm using a pointer cast here because null pointers contextually convert to false.