# why does setting a reference of a struct equal to another struct only change one data member?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

When I try this code
the output I get is

```
1 1 | 1 2
```

However if I get rid of the reference, i.e.

```
// replace 
A& a_ref = b2;  
a_ref = b1;
// with 
b2 = b1;
```

the output changes to

```
1 1 | 1 1
```

and I cant find any website that explains why this happens. Can any one explain it?

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
 int foo;
};
struct B : public A {
 int bar;
 B(int x,int y) : bar(y) { this->foo=x; }
};
int main(void) {
 B b1(1,1), b2(2,2);
 A& a_ref = b2;
 a_ref = b1;
 std::cout << b1.foo << ' ' << b1.bar << " | " << b2.foo << ' ' <<
b2.bar << '\n';
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You assign to `A` subobject of `b2` object. `b1` is implicitly converted to `A`, since the type of the left-hand side is `A`. In other words, the assignment is equivalent to `a_ref = (A&)b1;`.

Comment: Further reading: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/501250)

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
A& a_ref = b2;
```

the reference `a_ref` is only referring to the members of `B` that are inherited from `A`. An `A&` can't know about the members of derived classes after all.

So when you do:

```
a_ref = b1;
```

the only members that are copied to `a_ref` are the members it knows about, which is only `foo`. So only `b2.foo` changes.

In this case:

```
b2 = b1;
```

You are copying all the members of a `B` object, so all the members get changed.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `A` reference, it could be tied to any derived type (same explanations holds true for pointers). The compiler allows tying it to any object so you can *forget* about its exact type, be it `A`, `B`, as long as it inherits from `A`.
Obviously it doesn't know about the internals of any derived type, which is why it just does `A` things.

This may be handled using virtual functions; in that case, the compiler takes care of putting a table with pointers to the *real* functions (not just those in the base type). As those functions share their signature, a caller can call any of them, not caring about what happens inside.

This said, you could define a virtual copy assignment operator, which would do what you expect... or maybe not!

I was fooled and thought you could, but you really can't... See
[virtual assignment operator C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669818/virtual-assignment-operator-c#669894) to know why.