Overloading the shift operator << in C++
As a university assignment I have to implement the ostream class of C++ standard library. I have header files with the function declarations and .cpp files, where I have to implement the functions declared in the header files. There are two classes, one called Stringbuffer and the other OutputStream. The class Stringbuffer composes single characters into a longer text that can be processed on block, and the class OutputStream corresponds to the class ostream from the C++ IO-Stream library. It composes output of variables of various data types. I'm facing a problem as to how I can implement the operator<<, since both classes contain virtual functions.
#include "stringbuffer.h"

class OutputStream {
    OutputStream(const OutputStream&)            = delete;
    OutputStream& operator=(const OutputStream&) = delete;

 public:

    OutputStream();

    virtual void flush() = 0;

    OutputStream& operator << (char c);

    OutputStream& operator << (unsigned char c);

    OutputStream& operator << (const char* string);

    OutputStream& operator << (bool b);

    OutputStream& operator << (int ival);
};

class Stringbuffer {
    // Prevent copies and assignments
    Stringbuffer(const Stringbuffer&)            = delete;
    Stringbuffer& operator=(const Stringbuffer&) = delete;

 protected:
    /// buffer containing characters that will be printed upon flush()
    /// put() keeps this buffer always '\0'-terminated
    char buffer[80 + 1];
    /// current position in the buffer
    long unsigned pos;


    Stringbuffer() { pos = 0; }

    // Inserts a character into the buffer.
    void put(char c);

    virtual void flush() = 0;

 public:

    virtual ~Stringbuffer() { }
};

How can I implement the operator overloading? I'm guessing the OutputStream class has to inherit from the Stringbuffer class to have access to the buffer and put. But since both are abstract classes I cannot instantiate them and have access to buffer and put. I also have another class that inherits from these classes callled ConsoleOut, which writes text on the console.
#include "outputstream.h"

class ConsoleOut : public OutputStream {
    // Prevent copies and assignments
    ConsoleOut(const ConsoleOut&)            = delete;
    ConsoleOut& operator=(const ConsoleOut&) = delete;

 public:

    ConsoleOut();

    // Output the string on the screen.
    virtual void flush() override;
};


Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1115019 . While not about <<, this post also offers some info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/669818. Also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.

Can we have a [mre] please, rather than 3 separate chunks of code.  Thanks,

@PaulSanders That's actually the most important part. What I have posted are the .h files. I have to implement the functions declared in these files in the .cpp files. I have implemented the functions of the Stringbuffer class, and I'm stuck on the functions of the OutputStream class. How can I implement all the operator overloads is my question. I don't have anything else to post. I can however give more details about the individual functions and classes if it helps.

If you only have the headers because those were given to you as an assignment, that's important info. Please [edit] your question to clarify that then. Now, which of the functions to implement exactly is giving you problems? Which one isn't?

"'m guessing the OutputStream class has to inherit from the Stringbuffer class to have access to the buffer and put". Not necessarily. OutputStream could have a data member of a class derived from Stringbuffer, or a pointer or reference thereto. This is in fact the approach the standard library takes: ostream instance holds a pointer to streambuf-derived object.

@UlrichEckhardt all of the operator<< overloads in the OutputStream class for now. I did already implement the functions int Stringbuffer, and haven't started yet with the next class' fucntions ConsoleOut.

@IgorTandetnik Can you please provide a concrete example how that can be done in my code? Even a link to the implementation of the C++ standart library would be really helpful.

There's something odd about one of the class definitions -- the data members and member functions of Stringbuffer are all protected. Usually, the data members would have more restricted access than the functions (since you want people to use the functions instead of accessing the data directly). I understand you were given the header files, but could you verify that this is correct? buffer and pos are not private, and put and flush are not public? (Either of these would make access to the data more restricted than access to the functions.)

@JaMiT Yes, this is correct. buffer, pos, put and flush are all protected.

What is the connection between the two classes? How does that relate to the operator<< overloads? What is the code using those two together (I assume there is such code) which is giving you problems? Why do you even mention a second class if just one of them already gives you problems? The point is, you need to reduce the scope of your task just to a single problem (also see [mcve]) and then solve that. Don't just dump your homework here with a vague description of what it should do and the statement that you're "facing a problem". Be specific and restrict your question to one problem only!

@UlrichEckhardt As I already mentioned in my question my homework is to implement the ostream class of the C++ standart library. The Stringbuffer class has the purpose of collecting all the input before flushing it on the console, which is done by the ConsoleOut class. OutputStream should overload the << to make it work for various data types (this is needed, since ostream is not available, that's what should be implemented). Since Stringbuffer is an abstract class I cannot instantiate it and put characters to the buffer through the put method.

@UlrichEckhardt  I have no other code than the provided header files, othen than empty .cpp files.

"how I can implement the operator<<," -- A good first step would be to design the functionality. Don't worry about how to do something until you know what that "something" is. This is not a solution so much as finding a place to start. Start by thinking about OutputStream::operator<<(char c) since that's simple. What do you want to do with c? Put it in a Stringbuffer? Which Stringbuffer? Do you have one that will write to the console? It's often good to have your pieces working before assembling them into something larger. Maybe focus on flush before operator<<.
